# UISearchBar Small Cursor Glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am resigning responder for a `UISearchBar` that had previously *been* the first responder, in order to end editing and therefore remove the keyboard presented to the user.

I do this as result of presenting a custom alert window to the user by simply calling:

```
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

For whatever reason, I receive this result - a small tiny blinking cursor still showing in the search bar...

[image]

Really not sure as to how or why this happens... has anyone else had this problem / any ideas as to what could cause this? I know this is an odd / rare case but I just wanted to see if anyone on SO knows.. thanks!

Comment: what about `self.view.endEditing` ?

Comment: same result - the small cursor is harmless outside poor aesthetics but still very confused as to how it's even happening. It almost looks like the cursor is cut of before it finishes redrawing / animating the search bar (textField i guess here)

Comment: is this happen only for iOS 11 ?

Comment: Yup. 10 and below you could access the textfield

Comment: is there any UIScrollView you have used?

Comment: Have a table view - but I get the result even by simply calling resignFirst for a device connection change (if user loses signal)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 11+, the scrollView auto Adjust content inset. You can disable it by calling

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    scrollViewForView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
}
```

Comment: The scrollview is not connected to the search bar